# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. What Should I do?

Tags: python

so, I make a program to count the total of Matrix addition, Matrix reduction, and Matrix multiplication and I got an error

```
    matrix = []
    matrix2 = []
    matrix3 = []
    kali = []
    kali2 = []
    wrong = 0


    print("matrix A : ")
    for i in range(2):
        A = [] 
        for j in range(2):
             A.append(int(input())) 
        matrix.append(A)

    print("Matrix A : ")
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
        print() 
    print()
    print()


    print("matrix B : ")
    for i in range(2):
        B = [] 
        for j in range(2):
             B.append(int(input())) 
        matrix2.append(B)

    print("Matrix B : ")
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            print(matrix2[i][j], end = " ") 
        print() 
    print()
    print()


    print("matrix C : ")
    for i in range(2):
        C = [] 
        for j in range(2):
             C.append(int(input())) 
        matrix3.append(C)

    print("Matrix C : ")
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            print(matrix3[i][j], end = " ") 
        print() 
    print()
    print()

    while wrong < 1:
        choose = (str(input("(+/-/*)? : ")))
        if choose == "+":
            print("result : ")
            for i in range(2):
                for j in range(2):
                    print(A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j], end = " ")
                print()
            wrong = 0
        elif choose == "-":
            print("result : ")
            for i in range(2):
                for j in range(2):
                    print(A[i][j]-B[i][j]-C[i][j], end = " ")
                print()
            wrong = 0
        elif choose == "*":
            print('temp')
        else:
            print("error")
            wrong = 1
```

I type + after I type the array and I got this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in 
    print(A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j], end = " ")
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I've tried to make a new variable and change it to str but it won't work

```
                totalsum = A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j]
                totalsum = str(totalsum)
                print (totalsum)
```

I got this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in 
    totalsum = A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

It's still the same

Please help me

Comment: Using Python lists of lists as arrays seems awful when Numpy exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at where you've defined A and how you're adding your inputs to it, you'll notice that you're just appending ints one after the other. So instead of A looking like [[a,b],[c,d]] which is what I imagine you want, it looks like [a,b,c,d]. You could instead do something like Aprime.append(int(input()) and then append Aprime to A after the init loop for J.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalsum = A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j]
```

???

Is it not supposed to be :

```
matrix[i][j]+matrix2[i][j]+matrix3[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

*I've tried to make a new variable and change it to str but it won't work*

```
            totalsum = A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j]
            totalsum = str(totalsum)
            print (totalsum)
```

I suggest to not attempt guessing solution, without understanding first what is causing problem. Simple, but often effective method is `print`ing before feral line, that is you could do something like:

```
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

directly before `totalsum = A[i][j]+B[i][j]+C[i][j]` which should show that actually `A`, `B`, `C` are last rows of your matrices, that is just flat `list`s of numbers, by doing `A[i][j]` you are attempting to get `j`-th element of `i`-th element and in effect `j`-th element of number which does not make sense.